# Starting simple python web server in background and continue script execution

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

I am attempting to start a simple HTTP web server in python and then ping it with the selenium driver. I can get the web server to start but it "hangs" after the server starts even though I have started it in a new thread.

```
from socket import *
from selenium import webdriver
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import thread


def create_server():
    port = 8000
    handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", port), handler)
    print("serving at port:" + str(port))
    httpd.serve_forever()


thread.start_new_thread(create_server())

print("Server has started. Continuing..")

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://localhost:8000")

assert "<title>" in browser.page_source
thread.exit()
```

The server starts but the script execution stops after the server has started. The code after I start the thread is never executed.

How do I get the server to start and then have the code continue execution?

Comment: You are executing `create_server()` before you `start_new_thread` - which  will execute `serve_forever()` and you are stuck. Put it inside `lambda` for example.

Comment: If the thread never finishes its task, it shouldn't progress beyond the line where it starts.

Comment: You should use `thread.start_new_thread(create_server)` (notice the missing brackets) because otherwise you'd be calling the function itself instead of having the threading code do that for you. Even better, use the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module for a far more comfortable higher level interface for threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your thread with function `create_server` (without calling it `()`):

```
thread.start_new_thread(create_server, tuple())
```

If you call `create_server()`, it will stop at `httpd.serve_forever()`.

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3 you can use this:

```py
import threading

threading.Thread(target=create_server).start()
```